# A good pixel art drawer for Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: software-recommendation, 14.10

Another question to do with my friend’s lack of internet access and requirement of me asking questions for him.

So, he has decided that he wishes to do lots of pixel art drawings, and we are looking for a good pixel-precise-capable drawer with 100% accurate and clean multiple-of-100 resizes and multiple-of-90-degrees-angle rotations, etc.

So what is available out there for Ubuntu 14.10 in this area...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [pinta [image: Install pinta]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pinta).

You can install it from the software centre by clicking above, or you can grab the daily  build **(not recommended!!!)** from a PPA:

`ppa:pinta-maintainers/pinta-daily`

Here's a screenshot for greater glory:
[image: Sup.]